# How to get the rowNum based on a column value without using group by clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, row-number, rownum

I have an Oracle table structure that is similar to the following table called my_data

```
(CHILD, ROOT)
```

with the following sample data within my_data:

```
CHILD   ROOT   
-----------------
AA          A                   
AB          A                   
AAA         A                  
BB          B                   
BBB         B                  
BBBA        B                
BBBB        B
C1          C
C2          C
C3          C
C4          C
C5          C
C6          C
C7          C
C8          C
```

Based on the above sample data I need to produce a SQL query that returns the following information, i.e.:

```
CHILD   ROOT   ROWNO 
---------------------
AA          A         1          
AB          A         2          
AAA         A         3          
BB          B         1          
BBB         B         2         
BBBA        B         3          
BBBB        B         4 
C1          C         1
C2          C         2
C3          C         3
C4          C         4 
C5          C         5
C6          C         6
C7          C         7
C8          C         8
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT ROOT, CHILD, ROWNUM AS ROWNO  
 FROM (
 SELECT PARENT AS PARENT
 , CONNECT_BY_ROOT(PARENT)ROOT 
 , CHILD     
  FROM MY_DATA
 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR CHILD = PARENT
 ) A
```

Appreciate any help !

Answer (score 2):

`rownum` is a pseudo-column generated when Oracle builds result set. It is always incrementing. What you need is a `row_number()` function to generate new value for each group. Since you assign ordinal based on prefixes you may assign row number according to the prefix length and an actual value for prefixes of the same length.

```
with sample_data(CHILD, ROOT) as (

  select 'AA',      'A' from dual union all
  select 'AB',      'A' from dual union all
  select 'AAA',     'A' from dual union all
  select 'BB',      'B' from dual union all
  select 'BBB',     'B' from dual union all
  select 'BBBA',    'B' from dual union all
  select 'BBBB',    'B' from dual union all
  select 'C1',      'C' from dual union all
  select 'C2',      'C' from dual union all
  select 'C3',      'C' from dual union all
  select 'C4',      'C' from dual union all
  select 'C5',      'C' from dual union all
  select 'C6',      'C' from dual union all
  select 'C7',      'C' from dual union all
  select 'C8',      'C' from dual
)
select
  sample_data.*,
  row_number() over(partition by root order by lengthc(child) asc, child asc) as rn
from sample_data
```

| CHILD | ROOT | RN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | A | 1 |
| AB | A | 2 |
| AAA | A | 3 |
| BB | B | 1 |
| BBB | B | 2 |
| BBBA | B | 3 |
| BBBB | B | 4 |
| C1 | C | 1 |
| C2 | C | 2 |
| C3 | C | 3 |
| C4 | C | 4 |
| C5 | C | 5 |
| C6 | C | 6 |
| C7 | C | 7 |
| C8 | C | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6F7w89kX)

Comment: @Ravva adding the query for your reference

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Astentx. Much appreciated. I tried the mentioned code , but the query keeps on running without any results. I have noticed that in ORACLE group by / order by clause takes too long to execute along with CONNECT_BY.  Please suggest

Comment: @codeplex It depends on the source query. Oracle is not able to produce any result until it exhaust all the hierarchy downstream. But you've provided a plain source data and recursion is not required for it. If your original data is in parent/child form, then it may be better to implement per-level calculation instead of processing all rows in one pass. Anyway you need to investigate performance issues with, for example `dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor`

Comment: thanks for your response @Astentx .This is a sample data. My original data is in parent/child form, & its more than 200 million and not sure how to implement the logic for rownum. As the query keeps on executing , and after a period of time it throws tablespace error. Request your recommendation.